# docker-compose exited with code 1 Errno 2 Name or Service not known

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm following along with a tutorial and when I go to run docker-compose up it exits with code 1.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./project
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0. --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.1-slim-buster

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y install netcat gcc \
&& apt-get clean

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

Logs

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/usr/src/app']
ERROR:    [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

The docker-compose is in a root folder with a project directory next to it. The Dockerfile is in that project directory.

Comment: I solved my problem...

I just realized I had a typo in the port by adding an extra . after 0.0.0.0 and that was somehow breaking it.

Comment: (Consider making that line be the image's standard `CMD`, rather than having to provide an override Compose `command:`.  You should not need the `volumes:` block since the application code is `COPY`ed into the image.)

Comment: Good catch with the CMD, but isn't the point of the volumes block so that I don't have to rebuild it every time I make a change? Currently following a tutorial so there's changes quite often and having to rebuild it every time would be tedious